# Finding web element of dynamic websites using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to scrape text of few fields on the basis of their web elements (xpath, classes etc).

```html
<div class = myOnlyElement>
  <div> ......
    <div class = afafasf> ......</div>
    <div class = klklkl> ......
      <div class = qwqwqwq> ......
        <div class = reaction> text i need</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = myElement>
  <div> ......
    <div class = dfdfdf> ......</div>
    <div class = ghgghghg> ......
      <div class = erererere> ......
        <div class = reaction> text i don't need</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Suppose I have backend of element like this. I find element like:

```
myelem = driver.find_element_by_classname('myOnlyElement')
```

Now I only want to pick class "reaction" with text I need.
I am doing like:

```
myelem.find_element_by_classname('reaction')
```

if this class is present it captures it, but in some cases it goes for `class = "reaction"` whose text is "text i don't need"

Hope I have clearly mentioned my question. Can you please help me

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name is the proper syntax.

Comment: Also just check if you got myelem. Or use waits.

Comment: you can use find elements to get an array of elements matching the class... then iterate and get InnerHTML: thiselement.get_attribute('innerHTML') to find out if it's text you need or don't need.

Comment: The thing is whenever i visit any link, i want to get information from very first element. if it is present there or not. if element is present, get the text, if element is not present print "no text"

Answer (score 0):

my friend, best solution when it comes to this stuff, right click on the webpage, where you see the text. Right click in the DOM inspector and click Copy -> Copy Full XPath value. then you might need to do .text .source to get those values. but try and play around.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. But fullXPATH doesn't work in case of dynamic websites. its keep on changing.

Comment: this is unfortunately true.. sorry my friend

Answer (score 0):

To print the text **text i need** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.myOnlyElement div.reaction").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='myOnlyElement']//div[@class='reaction']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text **text i need** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myOnlyElement div.reaction"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='myOnlyElement']//div[@class='reaction']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)